# Create table using query on django

Tags: mysql, sql, django

I want to create a table using some columns from my original model using an SQL Query but I just can't do that.
I did the following but it does show all the columns but just the values for the columns selected. I want to generate a table just with the values selected:

```
def listing(request):
    table = Example.objects.values('nome','data_nascimento','nivel_academico','curso','instituicao')
    return render(request, 'listDB.html', {'latest_match_list':table, 'user':request.user.username})
```

Comment: How are you using it in the template and what result are you seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `python manage.py sqlall applabel` to generate the create table and initial-data SQL.

See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#sqlall-app-label-app-label).

> Prints the CREATE TABLE and initial-data SQL statements for the given app name(s).